# 2d Grid - Iterating by Rows / Cells - Take #2

Tags: c++, array, matrix, iterator, c++20

##### Preface

Following my first POC version:
[2d Grid - Iterating by Rows / Cells](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270281/2d-grid-iterating-by-rows-cells)

I have gained much more understanding, and present

##### A new version

A new version is ready, with templates and an attempt at using reusable classes, `Iterable` and `Iterator`.

It works as shown from the unit tests, but it does not support iterating over a `const Grid`. Since an iterator should it itself be const because `operator++` needs to modify its state, the STL library handle it though the `const_iterator` inheritance and much complex things.

It is also challenging to avoid having both default and non-default constructors. For example when `Iterable` is used as a base class, it needs to be initialized in the class initializer section, but at that point of time the arguments for it are not ready yet. This means that `Iterable` can be in an invalid state, it would be nicer not to be the case.

##### What I think makes it complex

A point of difficult is that I want grid to be linear in memory, instead of having a list of rows containing a list of cells. So the RowsIterator has to *cheat* and cannot simply increment itself;

**How should this be done to be elegant and support const iteration?**
Thank you very much for your time and priceless advice.

##### The relevant code

**iterable.hpp**

```
#pragma once

namespace shoujin {

template<typename T>
class Iterable {
public:
    Iterable() :
        _begin{},
        _end{}
    {}

    Iterable(T begin, T end) :
        _begin{begin},
        _end{end}
    {}

    [[nodiscard]] T begin() { return _begin; }
    [[nodiscard]] T end() { return _end; }
    [[nodiscard]] const T begin() const { return _begin; }
    [[nodiscard]] const T end() const { return _end; }
    [[nodiscard]] const T cbegin() const { return _begin; }
    [[nodiscard]] const T cend() const { return _end; }

    void Reset(T begin, T end)
    {
        _begin = begin;
        _end = end;
    }

private:
    T _begin, _end;
};

}
```

**iterator.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <iterator>

namespace shoujin {

template<typename T>
class Iterator {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    Iterator() :
        _it{},
        _step{}
    {}

    Iterator(pointer begin, int step = 1) :
        _it{begin},
        _step{step}
    {}

    void Reset(pointer begin, int step = 1)
    {
        _it = begin;
        _step = step;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] reference operator*() { return *_it; }

    [[nodiscard]] pointer operator->() { return _it; }

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        _it += _step;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int)
    {
        auto self = *this;
        ++*this;
        return self;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] friend bool operator==(const Iterator&, const Iterator&) = default;

private:
    pointer _it;
    int _step;
};

}
```

**grid.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "iterable.hpp"
#include <vector>

namespace shoujin {

template<typename T>
class Grid : public Iterable<T*> {
public:
    template<typename T>
    class RowIterator : public Iterable<T*> {
    public:
        RowIterator() {}

        RowIterator(T* begin, T* end) :
            Iterable<T*>{begin, end}
        {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    class RowsIterator {
    public:
        RowsIterator() {}

        RowsIterator(T* begin, int step) :
            _it{begin},
            _step{step}
        {}

        [[nodiscard]] RowIterator<T>& operator*()
        {
            _row_iterator.Reset(_it, _it + _step);
            return _row_iterator;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] RowIterator<T>* operator->()
        {
            _row_iterator.Reset(_it, _it + _step);
            return &_row_iterator;
        }

        RowsIterator& operator++()
        {
            _it += _step;
            return *this;
        }

        RowsIterator operator++(int)
        {
            auto self = *this;
            ++*this;
            return self;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] friend bool operator==(const RowsIterator& lhs, const RowsIterator& rhs)
        {
            return lhs._it == rhs._it;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] friend bool operator!=(const RowsIterator& lhs, const RowsIterator& rhs)
        {
            return lhs._it != rhs._it;
        }

    private:
        T* _it;
        int _step;
        RowIterator<T> _row_iterator;
    };

    Grid(int width, int height) :
        _width{width},
        _height{height}
    {
        _construct();
    }

    template<int width, int height>
    static Grid<T> CreateFromArray(const std::array<T, width * height>& array)
    {
        Grid<T> grid(width, height);
        auto* data = grid.data();
        for(int i = 0, size = width * height; i < size; ++i)
            data[i] = array[i];
        return grid;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] int width() const { return _width; }
    [[nodiscard]] int height() const { return _height; }
    [[nodiscard]] size_t size() const { return _data.size(); }
    [[nodiscard]] T* data() const { return _data.data(); }
    [[nodiscard]] T& operator[](int index) const { return _data[index]; }
    [[nodiscard]] T* data() { return _data.data(); }
    [[nodiscard]] T& operator[](int index) { return _data[index]; }

    Iterable<RowsIterator<T>> Rows()
    {
        T* begin = _data.data();
        T* end = begin + _data.size();
        return Iterable<RowsIterator<T>>{{begin, _width}, {end, _width}};
    }

private:
    int _width, _height;
    std::vector<T> _data;

    void _construct()
    {
        _data.resize(_width * _height);
        Iterable<T*>::Reset(_data.data(), _data.data() + _data.size());
    }
};

}
```

**Less important but included for completion: grid_test.cpp**

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

#include "../../src/grid/grid.hpp"
#include "assist/grid_assist.hpp"
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace shoujin;

TEST_CLASS(GridTest) {
public:
    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Ctor_WidthHeightSizeInitialized) {
        //Arrange
        const int kWidth = 2, kHeight = 3;

        //Act
        Grid<int> grid(kWidth, kHeight);

        //Assert
        Assert::AreEqual(kWidth, grid.width());
        Assert::AreEqual(kHeight, grid.height());
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(kWidth * kHeight, grid.size());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(LinearIterate_OK) {
        //Arrange
        Grid<int> grid(5, 4);
        std::vector<int> result;

        //Act
        for(auto&& it : grid)
            result.push_back(it);

        //Assert
        Assert::AreEqual(grid.size(), result.size());
        size_t end = grid.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < end; ++i)
            Assert::AreEqual(grid[i], result[i]);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IterateRangeFor_OK) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr int width = 5, height = 6;
        constexpr int array_size = width * height;
        auto arr = assist::CreateIntArray<array_size>();
        auto grid = Grid<int>::CreateFromArray<width, height>(arr);
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{width, height};

        //Act
        for(int y = 0; auto&& row : grid.Rows()) {
            for(auto&& cell : row)
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
            ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(arr);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IterateBeginEnd_OK) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr int width = 5, height = 6;
        constexpr int array_size = width * height;
        auto arr = assist::CreateIntArray<array_size>();
        auto grid = Grid<int>::CreateFromArray<width, height>(arr);
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{width, height};

        //Act
        int y{};
        auto&& rows = grid.Rows();
        auto&& row_begin = rows.begin();
        auto&& row_end = rows.end();
        auto&& row_it = row_begin;
        while(row_it != row_end) {
            auto&& row = *row_begin;
            auto&& cell_begin = row.begin();
            auto&& cell_end = row.end();
            auto&& cell_it = cell_begin;
            while(cell_it != cell_end) {
                auto&& cell = *cell_begin;
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
                cell_it++;
            }
            row_it++;
            ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(arr);
    }

    Grid<int> _make_grid(int width, int height)
    {
        Grid<int> grid(width, height);
        for(int i = 0; auto&& it : grid)
            it = ++i;
        return grid;
    }
};
```

**Edited - Added missing grid_assit.hpp / grid_assit.cpp code**

**grid_assist.hpp**

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace assist {

class GridVectorAsserter {
public:
    GridVectorAsserter(int width, int height);
    void Push(int row, int value);

    template<int Size>
    void AssertSameAsArray(const std::array<int, Size> array)
    {
        _assert_all_rows_same_size();
        _assert_match_array(array);
    }

private:
    int _width, _height;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> _expected;

    void _assert_all_rows_same_size();

    template<int Size>
    void _assert_match_array(const std::array<int, Size> array)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _height; ++i)
            Assert::IsTrue(_compare_row(_expected[i].data(), array.data() + i * _width));
    }

    bool _compare_row(const int* actual, const int* expected);
};

template<int Size>
std::array<int, Size> CreateIntArray()
{
    std::array<int, Size> array;
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        array[i] = i + 1;
    return array;
}

}
```

**grid_assist.cpp**

```
#include "grid_assist.hpp"
#include <cassert>

namespace assist {

GridVectorAsserter::GridVectorAsserter(int width, int height) :
    _width{width},
    _height{height},
    _expected{height}
{
    assert(_height > 0);
}

void GridVectorAsserter::Push(int row, int value)
{
    _expected[row].push_back(value);
}

void GridVectorAsserter::_assert_all_rows_same_size()
{
    auto size = _expected[0].size();
    for(auto& row : _expected)
        Assert::AreEqual(size, row.size());
}

bool GridVectorAsserter::_compare_row(const int* actual, const int* expected)
{
    bool result = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < _width; ++i, ++actual, ++expected)
        result &= *actual == *expected;
    return result;
}

}
```

**Also edited**
The code given above should now be enough to compile everything.
[Also here is the repo which contains more but unrelated code.](https://github.com/ShigotoShoujin/shigoto.shoujin/tree/stackexchange_post_270693)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Design review

> A new version is ready, with templates and an attempt at using reusable classes, `Iterable` and `Iterator`.

This is a bad idea.

Let’s start with `Iterator`. The problem here is that iterators are *extremely* purpose-specific. In other words, every time you make a new container, you almost always have to make a brand new iterator type for it. It is almost impossible to reuse an iterator from one container with another.

There are ~15 containers in the standard library, and your `Iterator` class would work for 3 (`vector`, `array`, `string`)… *maybe* 4 (`valarray`). Of course, it happens to work for your `Grid` because it’s just a `vector` under the hood.

But even for those few containers that it works for, it is wildly inefficient. Except for `Grid` of course (and only when used to iterate over rows, not elements). But that’s the point: iterators are purpose-specific. You needed an iterator for `Grid`; you made an iterator for `Grid`… but that iterator is *only* for `Grid`, and is extremely unlikely to be a good iterator for anything else.

Bottom line: iterators are not reusable. Iterators are *extremely* purpose-specific to a single container type. You cannot create a reusable iterator class.

The *desire* to create a reusable iterator class is not bad. [Even the standard library writers were tempted, and tried](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). But notice where it says “deprecated in C++17”? Even the designers of the language couldn’t make a sensible, reusable base type for iterators.

What about `Iterable`? That’s even more problematic.

In other languages, like Java, it is sensible—even necessary—to force interfaces via inheritance. In Java, for example, you might use the `Collection<E>` interface for your `Grid`. But that is not the way of C++. Your `Iterable<T>` would “work” as a base class for most containers… but in pretty much all cases, would be inefficient and brittle. Interestingly, that’s even true for `Grid`.

Indeed, you’ve already realized this. You already ran into the problem of initializing the `_begin` and `_end` members of `Iterable` in `Grid`’s constructor. But that’s just the tip of a very, very large iceberg of problems. Luckily you don’t have any functionality in `Grid` to resize the grid or clear it, or anything else that might invalidate the internal iterators of `_data`. If you did, you would have be *very* careful to keep `_begin` and `_end` up to date.

Even so, you have some serious bugs!

Consider what happens when you do this:

```
auto g1 = Grid<int>(3, 4);
auto g2 = g1;
```

Seems harmless, right?

Nope. See, when you copy `g1` into `g2`, the vector `g1._data` duly gets copied into `g2._data`. But here’s the thing… the `_begin` and `_end` members get copied, too… and they still reference `g1._data`’s data.

See for yourself:

```
auto g1 = Grid<int>(2, 3);
std::fill(g1.begin(), g1.end(), 42);

auto g2 = g1;
std::fill(g2.begin(), g2.end(), 69);

std::cout << 'g1 =>'
for (auto v : g1)
    std::cout << ' ' << v;
std::cout << '\n'

std::cout << 'g2 =>'
for (auto v : g2)
    std::cout << ' ' << v;
std::cout << '\n'

// expected:
//  g1 => 42 42 42 42 42 42
//  g2 => 69 69 69 69 69 69

// actual:
//  g1 => 69 69 69 69 69 69
//  g2 => 69 69 69 69 69 69
```

You see? When you keep running into complications (like the construction problem) that keep necessitating workarounds (like `Reset()`) and yet you still keep getting bugs… that’s the universe telling you that you’re doing something wrong.

`Iterable` and `Iterator` are bad ideas. They are overcomplicated, unextensible, error-prone, and even when they work, they are inefficient.

Again, the *desire* to avoid all the container boilerplate is not bad. Inheritance is just not the way to go about it. (The *right* way to do it would probably be to use metaclasses. But those are still many, many years away from being standardized.)

So just throw `Iterable` and `Iterator` out. They can’t be saved.

> **How should this be done to be elegant and support const iteration?**

`const`-correctness is the thing that most people implementing iterators get wrong. In fact, I noticed you linked to [an article about iterators](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp) in [your previous attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270281/2d-grid-iterating-by-rows-cells). That article is wrong in several places, but *especially* in the section “Make our iterator immutable”. The author writes this:

> By default, `Iterator` can alter the element it points to. If you want to make it immutable, the common trick is to add another iterator type to the custom container class — let's call it `ConstantIterator`. This new iterator type is almost identical to the original one, except for its dereference operator which now returns a *constant reference*:

```
const reference operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
// ^---- notice the 'const' here
```

So much wrongness and confusion in that short excerpt. `const reference` is ***NOT*** the same as `const_reference`. That confusion largely comes from the west-`const` fad, but even that doesn’t explain the cluelessness of the example code. The “notice the `const` there” `const` in that code does literally nothing at all; it’s completely meaningless.

The usual way to handle `const`-correctness with iterators is to make a templated internal iterator type for the container where the template argument controls whether it’s a `const_iterator` or not.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Grid
{
    template <bool Const>
    class iterator_base
    {
    public:
        using value_type    = std::conditional_t<Const, T const, T>;

        using pointer   = std::conditional_t<Const, typename Grid::const_pointer,   typename Grid::pointer>;
        using reference = std::conditional_t<Const, typename Grid::const_reference, typename Grid::reference>;
        // or:
        //  using pointer   = std::conditional_t<Const, T const*, T*>;
        //  using reference = std::conditional_t<Const, T const&, T&>;

        // ... etc.

        // Don’t forget an implicit conversion from iterator_base<false>
        // to iterator_base<true>!
    };

public:

    using iterator          = iterator_base<false>;
    using const_iterator    = iterator_base<true>;

    using pointer       = T*;
    using const_pointer = T const*;

    using reference         = T&;
    using const_reference   = T const&;

    // ... etc.
```

As an aside, this is another reason your `Iterable` class is broken… though it’s not your fault, because you were just following that article, and the article is wrong.

You see, you do this:

```
template<typename T>
class Grid : public Iterable<T*> {
```

And then in `Iterable`, you have (with some of the noise stripped out, and the template type replaced with `U` to avoid confusion with the `T` in `Grid`):

```
template<typename U>
class Iterable {
    U begin() { return _begin; }
    const U begin() const { return _begin; }
```

The first function is correct: `Grid<int>` inherits from `Iterable<int*>`, so `U` is `int*`, which is a non-`const` pointer to the `int` data in the internal vector. All good.

The second function is wrong. With `Grid<int>`, `T` is `int`… which means that `Iterable<T*>` is actually `Iterable<int*>`, which means `U` is `int*`. You might think that `const U` means `const int*`… but you’d be wrong.

To understand why, you have to realize that in C++, `const` modifies what’s on the *left*… not the right. `const` modifies what comes *before* it… not after. When you write `int const*`, the `const` is modifying the `int`… not the `*`. If you want a constant pointer, you need to write `int* const`.

Unfortunately, C++ says that if there’s nothing on the left, then `const` modifies what’s on the right. That’s why `const int*` works; since there’s nothing before `const`, it modifies what comes after—the `int`—so the compiler reinterprets it as `int const*`.

***BUT… IT… IS… WRONG.*** I am not saying this to start a fight, and I don’t care if anyone has a religious attachment to `const`-on-the-left. For the next few paragraphs, just bear with me, put aside your stylistic preferences, and *temporarily* accept that `const` should go on the right. It will make everything going on here make sense.

So since `const` is *supposed* to be on the right, that means `const U` is *actually* `U const`. So that second function is actually `U const begin() const`. But remember, `U` is `int*`. That means `U const` is `int* const`… ***NOT*** `int const*` (or `const int*`).

See the problem now?

- `int const*` is a pointer to a constant `int`. You can change the pointer (for example, you could increment it), but not the `int` it points to.
- `int* const` is a constant pointer to a non-constant `int`. You *can’t* change the pointer, but you *can* change the `int` it points to.

So when your `const` `begin()` function returns `const U` (which is really `U const`!), it’s actually returning `int* const`… which means you can change the data it points to… which means it can’t be a `const_iterator`.

- a non-`const` iterator would be `int*`.
- a `const` iterator would be `int const*`.
- `U` is `int*`.
- `U const` is `int* const`… which is *not* `int const*`.

I know it’s complicated, but so much of the complication comes from the fact that people like to put the `const` on the wrong side. If you just mentally rewrite it with const on the correct side—on the *right* side—you can avoid much confusion.

This is the same mistake that article makes. It says `const reference`—which, remember, is *actually* `reference const`—is a `const_reference`. But:

- `reference` is `T&`.
- `const_reference` is `T const&`.
- `reference const` is `T& const`… but all references are `const`, so that just boils down to `T&`.

So `const reference` is just `T&`… not `T const&`.

Incidentally, *any* function that returns `const` *anything* is probably wrong. Imagine a function that returns a `const int`:

```
const int f() { return 42; }
```

If you think that means the value returned can’t be changed… well… try this:

```
auto i = f();
++i; // !!!
std::cout << i; // prints 43
```

You see? The `const` is meaningless, because you’re copying the result into a new variable (in this case, `i`), and once copied, you lose the `const`ness. It (almost) never makes sense to return `const` *anything*.

So returning `const T` from the `const` `begin()` function doesn’t make sense at all. And even if it did, it would be a constant pointer to non-constant data… which is not what you want.

## Code review

Although I said that `Iterable` and `Iterator` should be discarded entirely, I’ll still give them a cursory review, because there’s always stuff to be learned.

### `Iterable<T>`

```
#pragma once
```

[Don’t use `#pragma once`, use include guards](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf8-use-include-guards-for-all-h-files). In addition to all the problems mentioned in the core guidelines, the reason `#pragma once` is so bad is because though it will rarely fail, when it does, it is absolutely catastrophic. It’s the absolute worst kind of bug: the kind that only happens intermittently—only on Sandra’s machine, and only on Tuesday afternoons, and only if she had tacos for lunch—and the kind for which there is no real fix. This is why `#pragma once` has never been standardized, despite *numerous* attempts.

On the other hand, if include guards ever fail, it’s so trivial to detect and fix that even someone who has *no clue about C++* can do it. It’s so trivial, you could write a bog-simple script to automatically diagnose *and fix*, maybe even putting in your pre-commit hooks.

Even better, since you’re using C++20, make it a module.

```
    Iterable() :
        _begin{},
        _end{}
    {}
```

As a general rule, you should `constexpr` everything unless you have a good reason not to.

Also, this kind of pattern is better handled by using member initializers:

```
template <typename T>
class Iterable {
public:
    constexpr Iterable() = default;

    // ... [snip] ...

private:
    T _begin = {};
    T _end   = {};
};
```

Doing it this way ensures the members are always initialized, even if you forget to explicitly do so in other constructors.

```
    [[nodiscard]] const T begin() const { return _begin; }
```

I already explained in the design review why the first `const` makes no sense here.

```
    void Reset(T begin, T end)
    {
        _begin = begin;
        _end = end;
    }
```

This shouldn’t be a public function; it shouldn’t be part of the interface.

```
    T _begin, _end;
```

[Never do this](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration). Declare each variable on its own line.

### `Iterator<T>`

```
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
```

I presume you chose `forward_iterator_tag` out of thinking that it would be better to be conservative if `Iterator` is going to be reusable. This is yet another reason why this pattern is a bad idea.

In fact, `Grid`’s iterators can not only be random-access, they can even be contiguous. The row iterators are a bit dodgier, because they’re really just going to be iterator *adapters*, basically just strided iterators (which I believe have been proposed, but are not yet standardized). Those are probably best left random-access.

Conservatively forcing `Grid`’s iterators to be forward iterators blocks many *massive* performance gains.

```
    Iterator(pointer begin, int step = 1) :
        _it{begin},
        _step{step}
    {}
```

I’m *really* not a fan of default arguments. They cause *way* more problems than they solve.

But if you *are* going to use one here, you should still mark this constructor as `explicit`. Otherwise bare pointers can be silently converted to `Iterator`s.

### `Grid<T>::RowIterator`

```
    template<typename T>
    class RowIterator : public Iterable<T*> {
```

The `template<typename T>` line is wrong. You don’t want `Grid<int>::RowIterator<int>`, you just want `Grid<int>::RowIterator` (similar to `std::vector<double>::iterator`). I mean, you’re never going to want the template type to change, right? You’re never going to want `Grid<int>::RowIterator<double>`, right?

### `Grid<T>::RowsIterator`

```
        RowsIterator() {}
```

Okay, first, you have a bug. Default constructed iterators should compare equal (but not necessarily equal to anything else). Because you have a pointer as a data member, the easiest way to do that is to set it to `nullptr`. So you *should* do:

```
constexpr RowsIterator()
    : _it{}
    , int _step{}
    , _row_iterator{}
{}
```

Or, better:

```
class RowsIterator
{
public:
    constexpr RowsIterator() = default;

    // ... [snip] ...

private:
    T* _it                       = nullptr;
    int _step                    = 0;
    RowIterator<T> _row_iterator = {};
};
```

But there’s a bigger problem here, a conceptual problem. What is a row iterator supposed to point to? A row? Okay, but what is a row? Judging by what your dereference operator returns, a row is an element iterator. Seems weird, eh?

There’s a simple solution here. A row is a [subrange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) of the whole grid range; it’s a view of `N` grid elements, starting at `M`, where `N` is width, and `M` is {0, width, 2 × width, 3 × width, … , height × width }.

So your row iterator could simply return `std::ranges::subrange`s. For example (not taking `const` iterators into account):

```
class RowsIterator
{
public:
    using value_type = std::ranges::subrange<typename Grid<T>::iterator>;

    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    using pointer   = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    constexpr RowsIterator() = default;

    // how to increment:
    constexpr auto operator++() -> RowsIterator&
    {
        // just move the begin and end over by the width (which is the size of the view)
        _row = value_type{_row.begin() + _row.size(), _row.end() + _row.size()};
        return *this;

        // and of course you can get random-access by simply multiplying
        // the size by n.
    }

    constexpr auto operator*() const -> reference { return _row; }
    constexpr auto operator->() const -> pointer { return &_row; }

    // ... and so on

private:
    RowsIterator(Grid<T>::iterator first, Grid<T>::difference_type width)
        : _row{first, first + width}
    {}

    value_type _row = {};
};
```

### `Grid<T>`

Okay, the first problem with `Grid` is that it inherits from `Iterable`. Because of that, there are two extra, unnecessary data members buried in the type: `_begin` and `_end`. These two data members add to the size of the type, but provide no real benefit, because the begin and end is already encoded in the vector. It also creates problems, because now you have to manually keep `_begin` and `_end` in sync… which, because you don’t with a copy constructor, creates the bug I mentioned in the design review.

Since `Iterable` serves no purpose other than to provide the `begin()` and `end()` family of functions, it’s easy to ditch.

(Speaking of the `begin()` and `end()` family of functions, in C++20 you only need to provide two versions of `begin()` and `end()`: `const` and non-`const`. Everything else, all the `cbegin()` and `rbegin()` and `crbegin()` functions, can be synthesized. Except you do need to add `cbegin()` and `cend()` for the container interface.)

What you should do, though, is realize that `Grid` is a container, and so you should provide [the proper container interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container). It’s actually not that bad: it’s just a handful of type aliases, and a few member functions like `swap()` and `empty()`. For all of them, you can simply defer to the vector.

Speaking of, you store both `_width` and `_height`. But since the vector already stores its size, you don’t need both. If you know `_width`, and you know `_data.size()`, then the height is simply `_data.size() / width`. You can ditch `_height`, and make the type even smaller.

So, as a starting point, `Grid` could be something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Grid
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    using reference         = std::vector<T>::reference; // or just T&, of course; I'm just illustrating
    using const_reference   = std::vector<T>::const_reference;

    using iterator          = std::vector<T>::iterator;
    using const_iterator    = std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

    using size_type         = std::vector<T>::size_type;
    using difference_type   = std::vector<T>::difference_type;

    constexpr auto begin()       { return _data.begin(); }
    constexpr auto begin() const { return _data.begin(); }

    constexpr auto end()       { return _data.end(); }
    constexpr auto end() const { return _data.end(); }

    constexpr auto swap(Grid& g) noexcept
    {
        std::ranges::swap(_width, g._width);
        std::ranges::swap(_data, g._data);
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(Grid const&) const = default;

    friend constexpr auto swap(Grid& a, Grid& b) noexcept
    {
        a.swap(b);
    }

    // ... and so on

private:
    int _width = 0;
    std::vector<T> _data = {};
};
```

It would even be easy to add allocator support, because you could just defer to the vector’s allocator.

```
    Grid(int width, int height) :
        _width{width},
        _height{height}
    {
        _construct();
    }
```

This constructor isn’t *bad* in any sense, but I would like to suggest that you avoid making the same mistake `std::vector` made.

See, `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a size. The problem is, it *also* has a constructor that allows you to set the vector’s data directly. The upshot of this is these two expressions:

- `std::vector<int>(10)`
- `std::vector<int>{10}`

do two different things.

You don’t have an initializer list constructor… *yet*… but you should leave open the possibility of adding one later.

There’s also another issue, and that is that it is easy to swap the width and height. Someone might write `Grid<int>(h, w)` by accident, and the compiler won’t notice.

So here’s what I propose.

Create strict alias types for `int` called `width` and `height`. Very simple, like so:

```
struct width
{
    int value = 0;
};

struct height
{
    int value = 0;
};
```

You could even improve these to allow detecting negative values, and so on.

Then make the constructor take those types instead of raw `int`s:

```
Grid(width w, height h)
    : _width{w.value}
    , _height{h.value}
{}
```

Now to construct a grid with width and height, you can do:

```
auto g = Grid<int>{width{10}, height{5}};
```

You could even make this sexier using UDLs:

```
constexpr auto operator""_width(unsigned long long int v) -> auto
{
    // optional: make sure v is valid (non-negative, and not too large)
    return width{int(v)};
}

constexpr auto operator""_height(unsigned long long int v) -> auto
{
    return height{int(v)};
}

// and now...
auto g = Grid<int>{10_width, 5_height};
```

Now it is trivial support mixing parameters:

```
// these can do the same thing
auto g1 = Grid<int>{10_width, 5_height};
auto g2 = Grid<int>{5_height, 10_width};
```

And you can support initializing with data:

```
auto g1 = Grid{width{2}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// produces:
//  1 2
//  3 4
//  5 0

auto g2 = Grid{height{2}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// produces
//  1 2 3
//  4 5 0

auto g3 = Grid{width{3}, height{3}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// produces
//  1 2 3
//  4 5 0
//  0 0 0

auto g4 = Grid{width{2}, height{2}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// error, too much data
```

I think that’s a pretty sexy interface. You could even go crazy and accept the width and height arguments in any order, interleaved in the data… but that’s probably not necessary.

```
    template<int width, int height>
    static Grid<T> CreateFromArray(const std::array<T, width * height>& array)
    {
        Grid<T> grid(width, height);
        auto* data = grid.data();
        for(int i = 0, size = width * height; i < size; ++i)
            data[i] = array[i];
        return grid;
    }
```

This is a decent function, but you should consider other types besides arrays, like maybe allowing constructing from vectors and such… basically, arbitrary ranges. As a very rough example:

```
template <int width, int height, std::input_range R>
static auto CreateFromRange(R&& r)
{
    auto grid = Grid<T>(width, height);

    auto first = std::ranges::begin(r);
    auto const last = std::ranges::end(r);

    for (auto p = grid.data(); (p < (grid.data() + (width * height))) and first != last; ++p, ++first)
        *p = *first;

    return grid;
}
```

You could even be more clever by reserving the vector space, and then constructing as you go, to account for non-default constructible types.

```
    [[nodiscard]] T* data() const { return _data.data(); }
    [[nodiscard]] T& operator[](int index) const { return _data[index]; }
    [[nodiscard]] T* data() { return _data.data(); }
    [[nodiscard]] T& operator[](int index) { return _data[index]; }
```

The `const` versions should return `const` pointers and references.

```
    Iterable<RowsIterator<T>> Rows()
    {
        T* begin = _data.data();
        T* end = begin + _data.size();
        return Iterable<RowsIterator<T>>{{begin, _width}, {end, _width}};
    }
```

So, what you seem to be doing here is using `Iterable` as a subrange… rather than a base class… and returning a subrange of subranges. This isn’t a bad idea, except for the fact that `Iterable` is a poor subrange class. You might as well use the standard subrange class:

```
constexpr auto Rows() const
{
    return std::ranges::subrange{
        RowsIterator{_data.begin(), _width},
        RowsIterator{_data.end(), _width}};
}
```

### Test code

You actually wrote proper tests for you code! Wonderful! So few people do. Your tests are also very well written and organized, too.

Unfortunately, I couldn’t compile the test code due to a missing header.

```
    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<Grid<int>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<Grid<int>>);
    }
```

In their review, @Toby Speight says you should use static asserts here, rather than tests. I ***STRONGLY*** disagree. That’s completely wrong-headed, and defeats the purpose of continuous integration.

In a real-world development cycle, you want as much test code as possible to run each time the testing is done… that’s the whole point of using a test framework, and writing tests that are independent of each other. Otherwise you’re just wasting compute resources. If the tests die at the compile stage due to static asserts, you get *only* the information about those specific static asserts—and, not in the framework’s format, so it won’t show up properly on your test result viewer, if any—so if there are any other failing tests, you don’t learn about them until the *next* check-in and test cycle. That’s just wasted time.

If you do it this way, and for some reason, the class becomes non-move-assignable (for example), when I check in the code, a few minutes later, I get an email telling me which test failed, and even which assertion failed. It would say something like “Test `IsMoveAssignable` failed; assertion `std::is_move_assignable_v<Grid<int>>` failed”. That’s laser-focused information; even with just a glance at the email—not even looking at the code yet—I know *exactly* what’s wrong.

On the other hand, if I used static assertions, I would get an email just saying “compilation failed, check the logs”, and I would now have to open up the compile logs, read through the compiler output—which is often extensive and verbose, and varies from compiler to compiler (you should run CI tests on multiple compilers!)—and try to figure out whether what’s happening is a test failure, or something else (like a compiler bug, or whatever).

There’s also the issue that there’s no guarantee that more than one static assertion ever fires. If the class is both non-copy-assignable and non-move-assignable, and you wrote the static asserts as illustrated, then only the second one—the copy-assignable test­—may fire. At the point the compiler is perfectly justified in stopping immediately. From what I’ve observed, most compilers are nice enough to keep trying as long they can before finally giving up. But that’s not guaranteed.

And it’s just inflexible. When I’m in the process of developing or refactoring a class, it’s quite common that multiple tests are failing, but I’m only interested in one or two specific tests at a time. With a testing framework, I can specify which tests to run, and ignore the ones that I’m not ready to deal with. With static asserts, I can’t even find out if a test is failing or not, not without manually going in and mucking with the testing code by commenting out the static asserts… which is bad practice.

No, I say if you are testing a class’s interface, use the test framework. That’s what it’s for. Static asserts are ***NOT*** test tools. They are fuses, to catch catastrophic errors that would be disastrous even when you’re not testing. If you have a machine that’s doing a self-test on startup, you want it to stop the startup and report errors, if any… but you don’t want it to blow a fuse every time the startup test fails.

I would also suggest going further, and using range and iterator concepts to verify that your iterators are iterators, and your grid class and row view are valid ranges.

## Summary

- Drop `Iterable` and `Iterator`. It is functionally impossible to generalize iterators; they are *very* purpose-specific. And `Iterable` just appears to be a poor-man’s `subrange`… or not, because it seems intended to be used both as a base class and a subrange view. That’s just conceptually confused.
- Watch out for `const` correctness. `const iterator` is ***NOT*** the same as `const_iterator`. Marking return types as `const` is pretty much always wrong.
- Consider implementing `RowsIterator` and row iteration in general using subrange views.
- Consider making `Grid` a legit `Container`.
- Finally, consider adding more tests using concepts and such to verify that your grid, row view, and iterators all satisfy their respective requirements.

## Questions

### The Microsoft library vectors reusable?

I don’t have a copy of the MS library to look into, so I’m just guessing here… but I *suspect* what you’re seeing is a phenomenon called “SCARY iterators”.

(“SCARY” is an acronym, but I can’t remember what it stands for. The first word is “seemingly”, but that’s all I remember.)

So, imagine you have two `vector`s of `double`s, except one uses `std::allocator`, and the other uses `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`. First, suppose you’d written `vector` like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
class vector
{
public:
    // ... [snip] ...

    class iterator
    {
        // ...
    };

    // ... [snip] ...
};
```

(Ignore `const_iterator`s for now.)

Now, with that code, if you do:

```
auto v1 = std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>{};
auto v2 = std::vector<double, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<double>>{};

auto it1 = v1.begin();
auto it2 = v2.begin();
```

the types of `it1` and `it2` are different. Both are instances of the internal type `iterator` of `vector<T, Allocator>`, so they depend on the template arguments `T` and `Allocator`. They both have the same `T` (`double`)… but they have different `Allocator`s, so they have different types.

This has a cost. If you do:

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

then because the types of the iterators are different for the two vectors, two different copies of the `std::sort()` function are being instantiated there. This can lead to slower compiles, and code bloat.

So let’s step back, and refactor `vector` to look like this:

```
// This would probably be in a detail namespace, or, in a standard library,
// obfuscated by using double underscores.
template <typename T>
class _vector_iterator
{
    // ...
};

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
class vector
{
public:
    // ... [snip] ...

    using iterator = _vector_iterator<T>;

    // ... [snip] ...
};
```

*Now* if you do:

```
auto it1 = v1.begin();
auto it2 = v2.begin();
```

`it1` and `it2` have the same type. Both are instances of the type `_vector_iterator<T>`, so they depend on the template argument `T`. And they both have the same `T` (`double`). Even though both came from `vector`s with different allocators, the allocators aren’t relevant to the iterator’s type. Which means:

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

both of these lines instantiate the same copy of the `std::sort()` function. That’s fewer templates for the compiler to instantiate, and fewer functions ending up in your binary.

SCARY iterators are iterators that don’t depend on anything but the container’s `value_type`. (That’s a simplification, because they can also depend on things like `difference_type` and `reference`. But let’s not get too far into the weeds.) That means they *don’t* depend on the allocator type. Turns out the allocator type is irrelevant to iteration; it never matters how a vector’s elements were allocated if all you want to do is iterate over them.

Note that even though `v1` and `v2` now have the same iterator type, it is still UB to mix them or compare them or anything like that. You don’t actually gain any new functionality, really. This is all about optimization. (Though, I suppose you could argue that now you could store iterators from the two vectors in the same container, and stuff like that.)

The key point though, is that this isn’t really about a “reusable” iterator. Even if you pull it out of the class, it’s still *only* a `vector` iterator, and can’t work for anything else in the standard library.

SCARY iterators are irrelevant to `Grid`, because the only template parameter `Grid` has is `T`, the `value_type`. If you wanted to make `Grid` allocator-aware, then it might be worthwhile moving the iterators out of the class, and making them depend only on `T`.

### `const` on the right? The left? (The middle?!)

I don’t want to sound like an evangelist telling everyone “this is the way you must do it!” I really don’t care if you prefer `const` on the left or the right. Actually the terminology in C++ lingo is [“east `const`” versus “`const` west”](https://hackingcpp.com/cpp/design/east_vs_west_const.html).

The only time it bothers me is when it creates confusion… and *this*—the whole `const iterator` versus `const_iterator` thing—this is the *prime* cause of `const` confusion.

I believe the only way to understand what’s going on and avoid the confusion is to use east `const`. If you *only* used east `const`, then you would never run into problems or confusion. You could see plainly that `const_iterator` and `iterator const` are completely different things, even before you expand (the expansions are `T const*` and `T* const`), and every way you look at it, it’s correct. The moment you starting mixing in `const` west, that’s when confusion starts to creep in.

*However*…

Once you *understand* what’s going on, I really don’t care if you prefer the look of `const` west. I work with both east `const` and `const` west code. I prefer east `const` only because I like consistency, but it doesn’t bother me either way.

So when I teach C++, I advise *thinking* in east `const`. I advise that whenever you see `const` west code, you mentally rewrite it to east `const` to make sure it makes sense. Once you’ve done that, and the code checks out, then you can go ahead and actually write the code as `const` west, if you like.

### What exactly does a `constexpr` ctor do differently then a ctor?

Pretty much nothing. The only thing it does is allow compile-time construction.

But this is rather important, and becoming increasingly so with each new version of C++. Now that even `vector` and `string` are `constexpr`, it’s a little weird when your type isn’t. Especially if there’s no pressing reason why it couldn’t be.

Technically, even if you don’t explicitly declare your constructor `constexpr`, the compiler is still allowed to execute it at compile time if it can. But when you mark it `constexpr`, you are *guaranteeing* that it can execute at compile time. This allows two things:

1. The obvious thing: it allows other `constexpr` code to use your type. This is important both for the current point, and the next.
2. It allows you to take advantage of the `constexpr` context for extra testing and security. You see, `constexpr` code ***CANNOT*** have undefined behaviour. If somewhere deep in your class’s code you accidentally dereferenced the end iterator, but didn’t actually do anything with it, your code might *run* just fine. Even the unit tests might not catch the problem. (Unit tests only test your class from the *outside*. If it does anything illegal internally, unit tests won’t catch it unless there are outside effects.) But the moment you try to run that code in a `constexpr` context, the UB will be detected.

So if you *can* make your class’s functions `constexpr`, you should. You make your class more useful, and you get free checking for it too.

### Why use trailing return style: `auto f() -> type`

Riddle me this: if I write `int x();`, am I declaring a function named `x` that returns an `int`… or am I declaring a default-constructed `int` named `x`?

What I’m getting at is that the “classic” C-based grammar is often vague and confusing. Modern C++ has brought a number of clarifying improvements. For example, if I wanted a default-constructed `int` named `x`, nowadays I’d write `int x{};`, or, even better, `auto x = int{};`. There’s no way either of those could be confused for a function declaration.

Similarly, if I wanted to write a function declaration, I’d write `auto x() -> int`. Again, there’s no way that could be confused for a variable declaration.

There are other factors I consider, too:

- As you know, `type f(...)` doesn’t always work. `auto f(...) -> type` always does. For example, when the return type depends on the arguments: `auto f(auto x, auto y) -> decltype(x * y)`.
- I usually don’t even bother to write the return type *at all*. I usually just let it be deduced. So I normally write functions like `auto f(...)`. I only add return types if deduction won’t work well (like when returning references), or when the return type is an important part of the interface (like, the whole point of the function is to return `bool`, for example).

I’m a big fan of consistency, too, and the trailing return type works for normal functions *and* lambdas:

```
auto f(...) -> type {}          // regular (possibly template) function
auto f = [](...) -> type {};    // lambda
```

And it just looks nicer when all your functions line up:

```
int func1();
std::pmr::vector<double> func2();
std::string func3();
auto func4(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b);

// versus

auto func1() -> int;
auto func2() -> std::pmr::vector<double>;
auto func3() -> std::string;
auto func4(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b);
```

90% of the time, it doesn’t matter whether you use old-school preceding-return style or trailing-return style. 10% of the time it does, and only trailing-return works. So either:

1. use preceding-return 90% of the time and trailing-return 10% of the time; or
2. use trailing-return 100% of the time.

Option 2 just makes more sense to me.

But again, this is a style thing, so I don’t really care if someone prefers something else, so long as they’re consistent.

### Named requirements, particularly `Container`

Note that in more recent versions of C++, the named requirements have a lot less weight than they used to have. Starting in C++20, concepts is the name of the game, and the concepts don’t always map directly to the named requirements.

`Container`, for example, requires:

```
struct Container
{
    using value_type = ...;

    using reference = ...;
    using const_reference = ...;

    using iterator = ...;
    using const_iterator = ...;

    using difference_type = ...;
    using size_type = ...;

    Container();

    Container(Container const&);
    auto operator==(Container const&) -> Container&;

    Container(Container&&);
    auto operator==(Container&&) -> Container&;

    ~Container();

    auto begin()       -> iterator;
    auto begin() const -> const_iterator;
    auto end()       -> iterator;
    auto end() const -> const_iterator;

    auto cbegin() const -> const_iterator;
    auto cend() const -> const_iterator;

    auto operator==(Container const&) const -> bool;
    auto operator!=(Container const&) const -> bool;

    auto swap(Container&) -> void;

    auto size() const -> size_type;
    auto max_size() const -> size_type;

    auto empty() -> bool;

    fried auto swap(Container&, Container&) -> void;
};
```

Now, some of those functions are usually auto-generated, like the destructor, and the copy/move ops, and `operator!=` can be synthesized from `operator==` in C++20. So we can simplify a bit:

```
struct Container
{
    using value_type = ...;

    using reference = ...;
    using const_reference = ...;

    using iterator = ...;
    using const_iterator = ...;

    using difference_type = ...;
    using size_type = ...;

    Container();

    auto begin()       -> iterator;
    auto begin() const -> const_iterator;
    auto end()       -> iterator;
    auto end() const -> const_iterator;

    auto cbegin() const -> const_iterator;
    auto cend() const -> const_iterator;

    auto operator==(Container const&) const -> bool;

    auto swap(Container&) -> void;

    auto size() const -> size_type;
    auto max_size() const -> size_type;

    auto empty() -> bool;

    fried auto swap(Container&, Container&) -> void;
};
```

That’s what you’d have to write to satisfy `Container` in C++20.

*However*… if you use C++20 functionality, like the ranges library, most of the above functions are unnecessary. For example, if you write `std::ranges::cbegin(c)`, that function will *try* to call `c.cbegin()`… but if that won’t work, it will try to call `c.begin()` with `c` made `const`. Similarly, you never need `c1.swap(c2);`; you can always use `std::ranges::swap(c1, c2);` and that will just work.

Which means that nowadays, you can just do:

```
struct Container
{
    using value_type = ...;

    using reference = ...;
    using const_reference = ...;

    using iterator = ...;
    using const_iterator = ...;

    using difference_type = ...;
    using size_type = ...;

    Container();

    auto begin()       -> iterator;
    auto begin() const -> const_iterator;
    auto end()       -> iterator;
    auto end() const -> const_iterator;

    auto operator==(Container const&) const -> bool;

    auto max_size() const -> size_type; // possibly not necessary

    fried auto swap(Container&, Container&) -> void;
};
```

Yup. You just need `begin()` and `end()`, in `const` and non-`const` varieties. (And, starting in C++23, using deducing `this`, you can get both varieties from a single function.) You *might* want to implement `size()` in some situations. But everything else can be synthesized.

If you need your grid to work with old code, then you probably need the full `Container` requirements. But modern code *should* allow you to simplify the class greatly.

((Added later…)) I forgot that even the type aliases can be synthesized nowadays, too. For example, you don’t need `typename Container::value_type`, you can use `std::ranges::range_value_t<Container>`. So, assuming that `max_size()` isn’t worth the effort (because when is that ever going to be useful in generic code?), that means that all you need for a type to “work” as a container in C++20 is:

```
struct Container
{
    Container();

    auto begin()       -> ...(1);
    auto begin() const -> ...(2);
    auto end()       -> ...(3);
    auto end() const -> ...(4);

    auto operator==(Container const&) const -> bool;

    friend auto swap(Container&, Container&) -> void;
};
```

The four types returned from the four `begin()`/`end()` functions can all be different, too. The only requirements are:

1. Must satisfy `std::input_or_output_iterator` (basically, just have operator `++` and unary `*`), *and*

   - must be implicitly convertible to (2).
2. Must satisfy `std::input_or_output_iterator`.
3. Must satisfy `std::sentinel_for<(1)>`.
4. Must satisfy `std::sentinel_for<(2)>`.

In practice, it generally doesn’t make sense for a container to have a different sentinel type, and you can generate both the `iterator` and `const_iterator` from a single template (as I illustrated above). So you really just need one type for all of (1)–(4).

Which means, this is about all you need:

```
template <bool Const>
struct IteratorForContainer
{
    using value_type = ...;

    using pointer = ...;    // optional, can be synthesized from operator->
    using reference = ...;  // optional, can be synthesized from unary operator*

    using difference_type = ...; // optional if random access (synthesized from binary operator-)

    using iterator_category = ...;
    using iterator_concept = ...;   // optional, unless you want contiguous iterators

    IteratorForContainer();
    IteratorForContainer(IteratorForContainer<true>) requires not Const;

    auto operator*() const -> ...;
    auto operator->() const -> ...; // not strictly required, but useful

    auto operator++() -> IteratorForContainer&;
    auto operator++(int) -> IteratorForContainer;

    auto operator==(IteratorForContainer) const -> bool;

    // only if bidi or better {
    auto operator--() -> IteratorForContainer&;
    auto operator--(int) -> IteratorForContainer;
    // } only if bidi or better

    // only if random access or better {
    auto operator[](difference_type) const -> ...;

    auto operator+=(difference_type) -> IteratorForContainer&;
    auto operator-=(difference_type) -> IteratorForContainer&;

    friend auto operator+(IteratorForContainer, difference_type) -> IteratorForContainer;
    friend auto operator+(difference_type, IteratorForContainer) -> IteratorForContainer;

    friend auto operator-(IteratorForContainer, difference_type) -> IteratorForContainer;

    friend auto operator-(IteratorForContainer, IteratorForContainer) -> difference_type;

    auto operator<=>(IteratorForContainer) const;
    // } only if random access or better
};

struct Container
{
    Container();

    auto begin()       -> IteratorForContainer<false>;
    auto begin() const -> IteratorForContainer<true>;
    auto end()       -> IteratorForContainer<false>;
    auto end() const -> IteratorForContainer<true>;

    auto operator==(Container const&) const -> bool;

    friend auto swap(Container&, Container&) -> void;
};
```

So it’s *much* easier to make a container in C++20.

But there’s another important lesson here. C++20 really goes all in on the idea that iterators are tightly coupled to their containers. In fact, it goes even further, and now, containers (and views) are *defined* by their iterators. See the code above? 3⁄4 of it is the iterator definition. Most of the container interface can be inferred or synthesized from the iterators.

The above is all you *need* to have a perfectly functional container in C++20. But it doesn’t *hurt* to support the older `Container` named requirement if you want. I mean, you’re already 70% of the way there already if you satisfy the C++20 requirements. Might as well add those aliases, and the handful of missing functions: `cbegin()`/`cend()`, `size()`, `empty()`, and the member `swap()`. (Oh, and `max_size()`, I suppose.) Especially since they’re all probably one-liners.

Comment: The Microsoft specific implementation of the std::vector iterators seems to use generic classes for const_iterator and iterator so I though it was better to do so. Thank you for reinforcing the idea that its more then ok but required to use specific iterator types.

Comment: > "Even the designers of the language couldn’t make a sensible, reusable base type for iterators."

So it make sense that I've been struggling so much with it only to reach an unsatisfactory result ^_^

Comment: "Even so, you have some serious bugs!"
"that’s the universe telling you that you’re doing something wrong."

Insert facepalm meme here.
I agree with the universe and shall hereby stop attempting to use *nice by intent* reusable iterators. Your post has set me free from this imaginary obligation.

Comment: Indeed metaclass are interesting https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/04/metaclasses-cpp-summary/

Comment: So it would seems that the `const` keyword should always be placed to the right of the type it affects, because when placed on the left there are confusions with typedefs and templates. However does it not get placed on the left mostly everywhere? Not a reason to keep doing it of course.

Comment: Noted on `#pragma once`, read some risk of using it. Too bad since its so much easier to type then a file prefix *and* suffix.

Comment: What exactly does a constexpr ctor do differently then a ctor?
I'm all for respecting the CPP Core Guidelines, about declaring only one name per line.

Comment: Great point on a constructor with only one non-default argument needing to be made explicit.

Comment: RowIterator was templated because it was originally declared outside of Grid, to make it easier to read and understand. Then once it was *working* I moved it inside of Grid. But yes no need to template it anymore.

Comment: Basically for RowsIterator the design would be to use subranges, and have operator++ change the active range. Interesting.

Comment: `constexpr auto operator++() -> RowsIterator&` Why use auto and specify the type at the end, it does not seems to be needed in this since the type is known from the start?

Comment: Just discovered the existence of named requirements, thank you! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req

Comment: The reason behind making Grid is handle pixel data from bitmap in order to make a colorpicker control, and I want to use range for for the rows/pixels instead of manually detecting rows change. With this in mind its not needed to add flexible initializers at this time, but could be since Grid is also meant to be used to handle any grids and not only pixel data. There is still much to learn concerning proper use of constexpr and the STL. You answered so much to let me make a better version, but maybe so much so that many new questions will come to light concerning STL compliant Containers.

Comment: CreateFromArray was added as a clutch to support existing unit tests through refactoring the grid. Thanks for the example on how to make it more generic.

Comment: This review is much appreciated !

Comment: Indi, thank you for writing the extensive design review that so clearly demonstrates my thinking in a much better explained fashion.  I often lack the time and/or focus to produce a well-targeted description of exactly what's wrong and how it should be written, but your answer goes above and beyond - bravo!

Comment: That's an interesting point you have about the compile-time-constant tests at runtime.  I'm fortunate enough in only having to consider a handful of compilers (just different versions of the same compiler, targeting just two or three different ISAs), and I've never been afflicted by a chatty compiler - if there's nothing wrong with the code, then a good compiler says nothing!  But for those in different circumstances, I can see how that helps - and you provide plenty of context for readers to make their own choices.  Thank you again!

Comment: @ShigotoShoujin Glad you appreciated the review! You asked several questions, and I think it will be easier to extend the review with answers, rather than trying to answer in comments. (Some of the questions are quite deep!)

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the kind words! The people who commonly write C++ reviews here—you included—are generally *excellent*. I may have quibbles with one thing or another, but meh, that’s how it always goes in extremely technical circles. Broadly speaking, I pretty much always agree with other C++ reviewers; I’m usually saying the exact same things they are, just more verbose. That’s my style: I like to think in terms of high-level design concepts rather than the nuts and bolts of code. Some people like that; some prefer more direct, code-focused reviews. I just try to offer an alternative.

Comment: Just realized that I forgot that the container type aliases can be synthesized too, so I’m expanding the end a bit.

Comment: Very nice, so the std::vector implementation use internal classes in order to optimize for less template instantiation, and not necessarily to make generic reusable classes.

Comment: On east and west const I would personally prefer east, but the west const is so much established that it seems counter intuitive to go against the world and use east. This alone is fine, but then consider that the STL types themselves use west const in their name; for example the `const_iterator` typedef is west, its not `iterator_const` (notice the '_'), so using a code style with east const will create contradiction when referencing names such as `const_iterator` that use west const and that we cannot change. Indeed they key is to understand how it all works.

Comment: Got it on constexpr, this confirms what I have discovered so far. Specifying all the ideal keywords do make things explicit however. Look at `[[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept`, we could argue over `[[nodiscard]]` not being worth it, but then the STL library use it because they think its worth it. We can argue about `noexcept` being needed only for move operator and being implicit in the dtor, but again the MS implementation of the STL library go all the way being explicit. Why not go full explicit? It does not make the program slower nor bigger.

Comment: On the trailing return type you are saying that you are using it even in the cases where its not needed, because it makes the code more readable and uniform. Same for seeing `auto x = int{};` easier to understand than `int x{};` and `int x = 0;` I think its like const, once you understand there is no confusion left.

Comment: Indeed your style makes a lot of sense. I'm just not ready to use auto everywhere at this time. I think auto is nice to avoid long, verbose type names.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the named requirements. I tried going with ranges, but on MS VS 2022 the range library is only fully available when using `/std:c++latest` and not in `/std:c++20`. Also its a good learning exercise and satisfaction to fix my grid the 'old' way.

Comment: I'm struggling with const_iterator, I though I would make a const_iterator class (nothing reusable, but specific), and an iterator class which inherit from const_iterator, so that iterator can be implicitly converted to const_iterator, with const_iterator having the const begin/end funcs and iterators adding the non const begin/end. This raise a CPP core guide warning E63 - do not slice. More investigation is needed.

Comment: Its fine now with const_iterator.

Comment: About using auto to make the code more readable, note that it might be best not to do this for unit test code. This way the test will not compile unless it the types returned are also the types expected. For example in `for(auto&& it : const_row)`, using `auto&&` *could* work even when `const_row.begin` does not return what we expect.

Comment: I’m afraid you’re still confused about `const_iterator`. `const_iterator` is not an example of west `const` because `const_iterator` has *nothing whatsoever* to do with `iterator`. `const_iterator` and `iterator` are two *completely* distinct types (remember you’re using a template to generate them… but different template instantiations are *completely* distinct types); there is no possible way to add/remove `const` and go from one to the other. Literally the *only* connection between them is that `iterator` implicitly converts to `const_iterator`. …

Comment: … It’s like “hot dog”. When you read that, you don’t think of an overheated canine (or a very attractive canine, I suppose). You don’t see two concepts (“hot” and “dog”), you see one single concept, indivisible, and completely distinct from the two sub-words that make it up. Same with `const_iterator`. It has nothing to do with an `iterator` being `const` in any sense. It’s not two concepts, it’s a single concept, indivisible. It is “`const_iterator`”: one single, indivisible thing… not `const` and `iterator`. …

Comment: … `const_iterator` is not a `const` `iterator`, it is an iterator that does `const` iteration… which is distinct from regular iteration; it has a completely distinct set of things you can do. Technically, `const` iteration is a subset of regular iteration… but not a *strict* subset. That’s what the `const` in `const_iterator` is about; it’s not saying the `iterator` is `const`, it’s saying it’s an iterator that does `const` iteration… which is different from plain iteration.

Comment: Personally I have no problem with `[[nodiscard]]` on functions that aren’t supposed to have interesting side effects, like accessors (like `begin()`). It’s noiser, but… . I don’t think it helps much, and I don’t think it’s *necessary* when ignoring the return isn’t actually problematic, but if you just feel like doing it by default… . I’m also all for `constexpr` everywhere. `noexcept` is a little trickier, because people often misuse it. They look at a function and see it doesn’t throw exceptions and then apply `noexcept`. But that’s not what it really means. …

Comment: … `noexcept` means “this function cannot possibly fail”. Like `begin()` cannot fail, no matter what state the grid is in, so it’s fine there. (If your iterators might fail when being constructed… well, that’s a whole other problem.) `operator[]` *can* fail though, if the grid is empty. (Note that even though `vector` sorta-kinda promises `operator[]` will not throw—unlike `at()`—[it’s still not `noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).)

Comment: Your concern about `auto` in tests is misguided. If you are at all concerned that `begin()` might not return what you expect, you should be testing *that*, and you should be testing it specifically in its own test. You shouldn’t be sneaking that test inside of other tests… and *especially* not by artificially adjusting the way you write code. If you expect most uses of your code will use `for (auto&&…)` (and you should), then write that in your test. …

Comment: … Writing the tests as generically as possible, as with `for (auto&&…)` is actually *good*, because it allows that test to continue working even when another test (the one that’s testing the return type of `begin()` or whatever) might be failing. That will help you find the exact problem easily. This is also why you should do as little as possible in each test… you want the only thing that might fail to be the test assertions, if at all possible, so you get very specific information about where and what the problems are. …

Comment: … My general rule of thumb for tests is that, except in the *very earliest* stages of developing a thing… like, the part where a test might fail because you literally haven’t written the class or function *at all* yet, even as a dummy stub… the *only* thing in your tests that should be failing is the test assertions. If something other than the test assertions is failing, you either have a bug you aren’t testing (which is really bad), or your class/function is complete garbage and should be discarded/rewritten with prejudice (because it is untested/untestable code).

Comment: The new grid is online https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272165/2d-grid-iterating-by-rows-cells-take-3

Comment: Agreed on `const_iterator`, maybe I misspoke, of course its not the same thing as `iterator`.

Comment: Improved the tests following your comments. See the new post.

Answer (score 1):

This code fails to compile, because the `RowIterator` and `RowsIterator` templates' parameter `T` both shadow that of the enclosing class, and because we use `std::array` without including `<array>`.

It's great that you have included the unit-tests, and they were easy to translate to a freely-available test framework, <del>but they depend on some functions in `assist` namespace you haven't shown, so it's still not possible to execute them.  That's disappointing!</del>

---

The first four unit-tests can be replaced with `static_assert()`s, to give earlier feedback, rather than having to wait until runtime:

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Grid<int>>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Grid<int>>);
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<Grid<int>>);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<Grid<int>>);
```

---

I think we have a misunderstanding here:

> ```
> [[nodiscard]] T begin() { return _begin; }
> [[nodiscard]] T end() { return _end; }
> [[nodiscard]] const T begin() const { return _begin; }
> [[nodiscard]] const T end() const { return _end; }
> [[nodiscard]] const T cbegin() const { return _begin; }
> [[nodiscard]] const T cend() const { return _end; }
> ```

`cbegin()` and `cend()` (and the const versions of `begin()` and `end()`) need to return **iterator to const**.  A *constant iterator* is not the same thing as a *`const_iterator`*, as it still points to a mutable value.

What we really need is something more like

```
using V = typename T::value_type;
[[nodiscard]] Iterator<V> begin() { return _begin; }
[[nodiscard]] Iterator<V> end() { return _end; }
[[nodiscard]] Iterator<const V> begin() const { return _begin; }
[[nodiscard]] Iterator<const V> end() const { return _end; }
[[nodiscard]] Iterator<const V> cbegin() const { return _begin; }
[[nodiscard]] Iterator<const V> cend() const { return _end; }
```

I wouldn't bother writing `[[nodiscard]]` for simple accessors such as this - that's more useful for functions with side-effects, and where the return value conveys information that can't be re-created.  The canonical example is `std::scanf()`, where ignoring the return value almost always¹ prevents writing a correct program.

---

Why do we have a private `_construct` member function, that's used only once?  As far as I can see, it serves only to assign to a member that should have been initialised instead, and to call a single base-class method.  Just put those in the constructor:

```
Grid(std::size_t width, std::size_t height) :
    _width{width},
    _height{height},
    _data(width * height)
{
    Reset(_data.data(), _data.data() + _data.size());
}
```

(Note that `std::size_t` is a better choice than `int` for the dimensions).

---

¹ "Almost" always - the exception being when no variables are to be assigned, such as `std::scanf("%*[^\n]")` to discard up to the next newline.

Comment: I've edited the post and added the grid_assist code, everything should now compile. The repo with the complete code is added but all required for compilation code should now be included.

Comment: Going for static_assert with std::is_ ... is quite clever, thank you !

Comment: Indeed the current version does not work for iterating with const, your example will help make the next version closer to what it should be.

Comment: Learning c++11/20 while coming from c++03 means that at first I though that every class needed copy/move ctor/operator=, and everyfunction needed noexcept and so on. It turns out it is not the case. Thank you for the clarification on when to use [[nodiscard]]

Comment: _construct was there because in an earlier version the base class had to be initialized using member variables, which by definition cannot be initialized before base class. This is an issue I am having, along with being forced to use default ctor followed by a call to Reset, which is a huge code smell.