# 2d Grid - Iterating by Rows / Cells - Take #3

Tags: c++, array, matrix, iterator, c++20

Edited with a bit more unit tests.

##### Preface

Following my second version:
[2d Grid - Iterating by Rows / Cells - Take #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270693/2d-grid-iterating-by-rows-cells-take-2)

I believe that I am now satisfied with this new version below.
There is still one area which I question whether it is a code smell or not.
A code review would also be much appreciated.

##### The solved problem

The need is to represent pixel data in contiguous memory, and seamlessly allow for iteration over rows / columns using range-for with such as

```
for(auto&& row : bitmap)
    for(auto &&pixel : row)
        //do something with pixel
```

Without this iterating would require one range-for over the whole data and manually keeping track of which row we are at.

All code is C++20 and should be efficient and nice and work on a const objects as well.
The grid is working and tested, but please help me find code smell and improvements.

##### How was the problem solved

To solve this, a generic `Grid<T>` is used.
The Grid itself is meant to be an STL container
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container

This Grid object is templated and can be used on any custom data.
Unit tests are present for a complete code coverage.

##### The remaining code smell, maybe

`RowIterator` inherit `ConstRowIterator`, and the former is using `const_cast` in `operator*` and `operator->`. This is also how the Microsoft STL vector implementation does it. Is the `const_cast` needed because of a bad design, or is it justified in this situation?

Same for `Rows` inheriting from `ConstRows`, but this time `ConstRows` also has a few `protected` variables reused in `Rows`. Again is that justified or is it needed because of a bad design?

##### Code Source - The Grid - grid.hpp

```
#ifndef SHOUJIN_SOURCE_GRID
#define SHOUJIN_SOURCE_GRID

#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace shoujin {

/// <summary>
/// Grid is a Container
/// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container
/// </summary>
template<typename T>
class Grid {
public:
    class Row {
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using const_pointer = value_type const*;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using const_reference = value_type const&;
        using iterator = pointer;
        using const_iterator = const_pointer;

        constexpr Row() = default;

        constexpr Row(pointer begin, pointer end) :
            _begin{begin},
            _end{end} {}

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return _begin; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator end() noexcept { return _end; };
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return _begin; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return _end; };
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return _begin; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return _end; };

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_t size() const noexcept { return _end - _begin; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference operator[](size_t idx) noexcept { return *(_begin + idx); };
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reference operator[](size_t idx) const noexcept { return *(_begin + idx); };

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr friend bool operator==(Row const& lhs, Row const& rhs)
        {
            return lhs._begin == rhs._begin && lhs._end == rhs._end;
        }

    private:
        pointer _begin{};
        pointer _end{};
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// ConstRowIterator is a LegacyBidirectionalIterator
    /// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator
    /// </summary>
    class ConstRowIterator {
    public:
        using value_type = Row;
        using pointer = value_type const*;
        using reference = value_type const&;
        using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

        constexpr ConstRowIterator() = default;

        constexpr ConstRowIterator(T* begin, size_t row_length) :
            _begin{begin},
            _row{begin, begin + row_length},
            _row_length{row_length}
        {}

        constexpr void swap(ConstRowIterator& right) noexcept
        {
            if(this != &right) {
                using std::swap;
                swap(_row, right._row);
                swap(_row_length, right._row_length);
            }
        }

        constexpr friend void swap(ConstRowIterator& left, ConstRowIterator& right) noexcept
        {
            left.swap(right);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type operator[](size_t idx) const noexcept { return {_begin, _begin + _row_length}; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference operator*() const noexcept { return _row; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr pointer operator->() const noexcept { return &_row; }

        constexpr ConstRowIterator& operator++() noexcept
        {
            _row = {_row.begin() + _row_length, _row.end() + _row_length};
            return *this;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstRowIterator operator++(int) noexcept
        {
            ConstRowIterator previous{*this};
            ++*this;
            return previous;
        }

        constexpr ConstRowIterator& operator--() noexcept
        {
            _row = {_row.begin() - _row_length, _row.end() - _row_length};
            return *this;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstRowIterator operator--(int) noexcept
        {
            ConstRowIterator previous{*this};
            --*this;
            return previous;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr friend bool operator==(ConstRowIterator const& lhs, ConstRowIterator const& rhs)
        {
            return lhs._row == rhs._row;
        }

    private:
        T* _begin{};
        Row _row;
        size_t _row_length{};
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// ConstRowIterator is a LegacyBidirectionalIterator
    /// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator
    /// </summary>
    class RowIterator : public ConstRowIterator {
    public:
        using pointer = ConstRowIterator::value_type*;
        using reference = ConstRowIterator::value_type&;

        constexpr RowIterator() = default;

        constexpr RowIterator(T* begin, size_t row_length) :
            ConstRowIterator{begin, row_length} {}

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference operator*() const noexcept
        {
            return const_cast<reference>(ConstRowIterator::operator*());
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr pointer operator->() const noexcept
        {
            return const_cast<pointer>(ConstRowIterator::operator->());
        }

        constexpr RowIterator& operator++() noexcept
        {
            ConstRowIterator::operator++();
            return *this;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr RowIterator operator++(int) noexcept
        {
            RowIterator previous{*this};
            ++*this;
            return previous;
        }

        constexpr RowIterator& operator--() noexcept
        {
            ConstRowIterator::operator--();
            return *this;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr RowIterator operator--(int) noexcept
        {
            RowIterator previous{*this};
            --*this;
            return previous;
        }
    };

    class ConstRows {
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using const_pointer = value_type const*;
        using const_iterator = ConstRowIterator;

        constexpr ConstRows() = default;

        constexpr ConstRows(const_pointer begin, const_pointer end, size_t row_length) :
            _begin{const_cast<pointer>(begin)},
            _end{const_cast<pointer>(end)},
            _row_length{row_length}
        {}

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return {_begin, _row_length}; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return {_end, _row_length}; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return {_begin, _row_length}; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return {_end, _row_length}; }

    protected:
        pointer _begin{};
        pointer _end{};
        size_t _row_length{};
    };

    class Rows : public ConstRows {
    public:
        using iterator = RowIterator;
        using pointer = ConstRows::pointer;

        constexpr Rows() = default;

        constexpr Rows(pointer begin, pointer end, size_t row_length) :
            ConstRows(begin, end, row_length) {}

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return {ConstRows::_begin, ConstRows::_row_length}; }
        [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator end() noexcept { return {ConstRows::_end, ConstRows::_row_length}; }
    };

    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = value_type const&;
    using iterator = std::vector<T>::iterator;
    using const_iterator = std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
    using difference_type = std::vector<T>::difference_type;
    using size_type = std::vector<T>::size_type;

    constexpr Grid() = default;

    constexpr Grid(size_type width, size_type height) :
        _vector(width * height),
        _width{width},
        _height{height}
    {}

    constexpr Grid(size_type width, size_type height, std::initializer_list<T> il) :
        _vector(width * height),
        _width{width},
        _height{height}
    {
        auto end = il.end() - (il.size() > _vector.size() ? il.size() - _vector.size() : 0);
        std::copy(il.begin(), end, _vector.begin());
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return _vector.begin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator end() noexcept { return _vector.end(); };
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return _vector.begin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return _vector.end(); };
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return _vector.cbegin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return _vector.cend(); };
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return _vector.empty(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return _vector.size(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept { return _vector.max_size(); }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type* data() noexcept { return _vector.data(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type const* data() const noexcept { return const_cast<value_type const*>(_vector.data()); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference operator[](size_type idx) noexcept { return _vector[idx]; }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type idx) const noexcept { return _vector[idx]; }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type width() const noexcept { return _width; }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type height() const noexcept { return _height; }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr friend bool operator==(Grid const& lhs, Grid const& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return lhs.width() == rhs.width() &&
            lhs.height() == rhs.height() &&
            std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());
    }

    constexpr void swap(Grid& right) noexcept
    {
        if(this != &right) {
            using std::swap;
            swap(_vector, right._vector);
            swap(_width, right._width);
            swap(_height, right._height);
        }
    }

    constexpr friend void swap(Grid& left, Grid& right) noexcept
    {
        left.swap(right);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Rows EnumerateRows() noexcept
    {
        return {data(), data() + size(), _width};
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstRows EnumerateRows() const noexcept
    {
        return {data(), data() + size(), _width};
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _vector;
    size_type _width{};
    size_type _height{};
};

}

#endif
```

##### Code Source - The tests - grid_test.cpp

**Included for completeness only**
Using the Microsoft CPP test framework.

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

#include "../src/grid.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace shoujin;

namespace assist {

class GridVectorAsserter {
public:
    GridVectorAsserter(int width, int height) :
        _width{width},
        _height{height},
        _expected{height} {}

    void Push(int row, int value) { _expected[row].push_back(value); }

    template<int Size>
    void AssertSameAsArray(std::array<int, Size> const array)
    {
        _assert_all_rows_same_size();
        _assert_match_array(array);
    }

private:
    int _width, _height;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> _expected;

    void _assert_all_rows_same_size()
    {
        auto size = _expected[0].size();
        for(auto& row : _expected)
            Assert::AreEqual(size, row.size());
    }

    template<int Size>
    void _assert_match_array(std::array<int, Size> const array)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _height; ++i)
            Assert::IsTrue(_compare_row(_expected[i].data(), array.data() + i * _width));
    }

    bool _compare_row(int const* actual, int const* expected)
    {
        bool result = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < _width; ++i, ++actual, ++expected)
            result &= *actual == *expected;
        return result;
    }
};

template<int Size>
std::array<int, Size> CreateIntArray()
{
    std::array<int, Size> array;
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        array[i] = i + 1;
    return array;
}

template<typename T>
Grid<T> CreateFilledGrid(size_t width, size_t height)
{
    Grid<T> grid(width, height);

    auto&& it = grid.data();
    auto&& end = it + grid.size();
    auto i = 0;
    while(it != end)
        *it++ = ++i;

    return grid;
}

}

using T = int;
using Row = Grid<T>::Row;
using ConstRowIterator = Grid<T>::ConstRowIterator;
using RowIterator = Grid<T>::RowIterator;
using Rows = Grid<T>::Rows;
using ConstRows = Grid<T>::ConstRows;

TEST_CLASS(Grid_RowTest) {
    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ValueType_IsType) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::value_type, int>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Pointer_IsTypePointer) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::pointer, Row::value_type*>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ConstPointer_IsTypeConstPointer) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::const_pointer, Row::value_type const*>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Reference_IsTypeReference) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::reference, Row::value_type&>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ConstReference_IsTypeConstReference) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::const_reference, Row::value_type const&>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Iterator_IsTypePointer) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::iterator, Row::pointer>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ConstIterator_IsTypeConstPointer) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Row::const_iterator, Row::const_pointer>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDefaultConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_default_constructible_v<Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_WhenRowIsNotConst_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Row row;

        auto actual = row.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Row::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_WhenRowIsNotConst_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Row row;

        auto actual = row.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Row::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_WhenRowIsConst_ReturnConstIteratorType) {
        Row const row;

        auto actual = row.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Row::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_WhenRowIsConst_ReturnConstIteratorType) {
        Row const row;

        auto actual = row.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Row::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingRangeFor_EnumerateEachValue) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        Row row{data, data + 3};
        int i = 0;

        for(auto&& it : row)
            Assert::AreEqual(++i, it);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingRangeForConst_EnumerateEachValue) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        Row row{data, data + 3};
        Row const const_row = std::as_const(row);
        int i = 0;

        for(auto&& it : const_row)
            Assert::AreEqual(++i, it);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Size_ReturnSize) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        Row const const_row{data, data + 3};
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(3, const_row.size());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscript_ReturnValue) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        Row const const_row{data, data + 3};
        Assert::AreEqual(2, const_row[1]);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscript_WriteToIt_Compiles) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        Row row{data, data + 3};
        row[1] = 5;
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscriptConst_ReturnValue) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        Row row{data, data + 3};
        Assert::AreEqual(2, row[1]);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenBeginEndMismatch_ReturnFalse) {
        int data1[]{1, 2};
        int data2[]{1, 2};
        Row row1{data1, data1 + 2};
        Row Row{data2, data2 + 2};

        bool actual = row1 == Row;

        Assert::IsFalse(actual);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenBeginEndMatch_ReturnTrue) {
        int data[]{1, 2};
        Row row1{data, data + 2};
        Row Row{data, data + 2};

        bool actual = row1 == Row;

        Assert::IsTrue(actual);
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(Grid_ConstRowIteratorTest) {
    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ValueType_IsType) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<ConstRowIterator::value_type, Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Reference_IsTypeReference) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<ConstRowIterator::reference, ConstRowIterator::value_type const&>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Pointer_IsTypePointer) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<ConstRowIterator::pointer, ConstRowIterator::value_type const*>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_DifferenceType_IsPtrDiffT) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<ConstRowIterator::difference_type, ptrdiff_t>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_IteratorCategory_IsRandomAccessIterator) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<ConstRowIterator::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDefaultConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_default_constructible_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDestructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_destructible_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsSwappable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_swappable_v<ConstRowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscript_ReturnSpecifiedRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 3};

        Row actual = c_row_it[1];

        Assert::AreEqual(1, actual[0]);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIndirection_ReturnCurrentRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 3};

        Row const actual = *c_row_it;

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *actual.begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorDereference_ReturnCurrentRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 3};

        ConstRowIterator::pointer actual = c_row_it.operator->();

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *actual->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIncrementPrefix_MoveToNextRowAndReturnIt) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 2};

        ConstRowIterator& actual = ++c_row_it;

        Assert::AreEqual(3, *actual->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIncrementPostfix_MoveToNextRowAndReturnOriginalRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 2};

        ConstRowIterator actual = c_row_it++;

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *(*actual).begin());
        Assert::AreEqual(3, *c_row_it->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIncrementPrefix_WhenUsedOnACopy_DoNotIncrementSource) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        auto c_row_it = ConstRowIterator{data, 2};
        auto c_row_it_copy = c_row_it;

        ++c_row_it_copy;

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *c_row_it->begin());
        Assert::AreEqual(3, *c_row_it_copy->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorDecrementPrefix_MoveToPreviousRowAndReturnIt) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 2};
        ++++c_row_it;

        ConstRowIterator& actual = --c_row_it;

        Assert::AreEqual(3, *actual->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorDecrementPostfix_MoveToPreviousRowAndReturnOriginalRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it{data, 2};
        ++++c_row_it;

        ConstRowIterator actual = c_row_it--;

        Assert::AreEqual(5, *(*actual).begin());
        Assert::AreEqual(3, *c_row_it->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenReferencingOtherRow_ReturnFalse) {
        int data1[]{1, 2};
        int data2[]{1, 2};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it1{data1, 2};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it2{data2, 2};

        bool actual = c_row_it1 == c_row_it2;

        Assert::IsFalse(actual);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenReferencingSameRowMatch_ReturnTrue) {
        int data[]{1, 2};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it1{data, 2};
        ConstRowIterator c_row_it2{data, 2};

        bool actual = c_row_it1 == c_row_it2;

        Assert::IsTrue(actual);
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(Grid_RowIteratorTest) {
    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ValueType_IsType) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<RowIterator::value_type, Row>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Reference_IsTypeReference) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<RowIterator::reference, RowIterator::value_type&>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Pointer_IsTypePointer) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<RowIterator::pointer, RowIterator::value_type*>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_DifferenceType_IsPtrDiffT) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<RowIterator::difference_type, ptrdiff_t>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_IteratorCategory_IsRandomAccessIterator) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<RowIterator::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDefaultConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_default_constructible_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDestructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_destructible_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsSwappable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_swappable_v<RowIterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscript_ReturnSpecifiedRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 3};

        Row actual = row_it[1];

        Assert::AreEqual(1, actual[0]);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIndirection_ReturnCurrentRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 3};
        Row& actual = *row_it;
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorDereference_ReturnCurrentRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 3};

        Row* actual = row_it.operator->();

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *actual->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIncrementPrefix_MoveToNextRowAndReturnIt) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 2};

        RowIterator& actual = ++row_it;

        Assert::AreEqual(3, *actual->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIncrementPostfix_MoveToNextRowAndReturnOriginalRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 2};

        RowIterator actual = row_it++;

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *(*actual).begin());
        Assert::AreEqual(3, *row_it->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorIncrementPrefix_WhenUsedOnACopy_DoNotIncrementSource) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        auto row_it = RowIterator{data, 2};
        auto row_it_copy = row_it;

        ++row_it_copy;

        Assert::AreEqual(1, *row_it->begin());
        Assert::AreEqual(3, *row_it_copy->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorDecrementPrefix_MoveToPreviousRowAndReturnIt) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 2};
        ++++row_it;

        RowIterator& actual = --row_it;

        Assert::AreEqual(3, *actual->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorDecrementPostfix_MoveToPreviousRowAndReturnOriginalRow) {
        int data[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        RowIterator row_it{data, 2};
        ++++row_it;

        RowIterator actual = row_it--;

        Assert::AreEqual(5, *(*actual).begin());
        Assert::AreEqual(3, *row_it->begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenReferencingOtherRow_ReturnFalse) {
        int data1[]{1, 2};
        int data2[]{1, 2};
        RowIterator row_it1{data1, 2};
        RowIterator row_it2{data2, 2};

        bool actual = row_it1 == row_it2;

        Assert::IsFalse(actual);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenReferencingSameRowMatch_ReturnTrue) {
        int data[]{1, 2};
        RowIterator row_it1{data, 2};
        RowIterator row_it2{data, 2};

        bool actual = row_it1 == row_it2;

        Assert::IsTrue(actual);
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(Grid_ConstRowsTest) {
    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<ConstRows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<ConstRows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<ConstRows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<ConstRows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDefaultConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_default_constructible_v<ConstRows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_ReturnConstIteratorType) {
        ConstRows const_rows;

        auto actual = const_rows.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), ConstRows::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_ReturnConstIteratorType) {
        ConstRows const_rows;

        auto actual = const_rows.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), ConstRows::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingRangeFor_EnumerateEachRow) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr auto kWidth = 3;
        constexpr auto kHeight = 2;
        constexpr auto kSize = kWidth * kHeight;
        auto test_data = assist::CreateIntArray<kSize>();
        ConstRows const_rows{test_data.data(), test_data.data() + kSize, kWidth};
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{kWidth, kHeight};

        //Act
        for(int y{}; auto&& row : const_rows) {
            for(auto&& cell : row)
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
            ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(test_data);
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(Grid_RowsTest) {
    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Rows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Rows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<Rows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<Rows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDefaultConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_default_constructible_v<Rows>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Rows rows;

        auto actual = rows.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Rows::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Rows rows;

        auto actual = rows.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Rows::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingRangeFor_EnumerateEachRow) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr auto kWidth = 3;
        constexpr auto kHeight = 2;
        constexpr auto kSize = kWidth * kHeight;
        auto test_data = assist::CreateIntArray<kSize>();
        Rows rows{test_data.data(), test_data.data() + kSize, kWidth};
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{kWidth, kHeight};

        //Act
        for(int y{}; auto&& row : rows) {
            for(auto&& cell : row)
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
            ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(test_data);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingBeginEnd_EnumerateEachRow) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr auto kWidth = 3;
        constexpr auto kHeight = 2;
        constexpr auto kSize = kWidth * kHeight;
        auto test_data = assist::CreateIntArray<kSize>();
        auto rows = Rows{test_data.data(), test_data.data() + kSize, kWidth};
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{kWidth, kHeight};

        //Act
        RowIterator row_begin = rows.begin();
        RowIterator row_end = rows.end();
        RowIterator row_it = row_begin;
        auto y = int{};
        while(row_it != row_end) {
            Row& row = row_it.operator*();
            int* cell_begin = row.begin();
            int* cell_end = row.end();
            int* cell_it = cell_begin;
            while(cell_it != cell_end) {
                int& cell = *cell_it;
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
                ++cell_it;
            }
            ++row_it, ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(test_data);
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(Grid_GridTest) {
public:
    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ValueType_IsType) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::value_type, int>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Reference_IsTypeReference) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::reference, int&>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ConstReference_IsConstTypeRef) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::const_reference, int const&>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_Iterator_IsVectorTypeIterator) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_ConstIterator_IsVectorTypeConstIterator) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_DifferenceType_IsVectorTypeDifferenceType) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::difference_type, std::vector<int>::difference_type>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Alias_SizeType_IsVectorTypeSizeType) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<Grid<T>::size_type, std::vector<int>::size_type>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDefaultConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_default_constructible_v<Grid<T>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Grid<T>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsCopyAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Grid<T>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveConstructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_constructible_v<Grid<T>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsMoveAssignable) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_move_assignable_v<Grid<T>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(IsDestructible) {
        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_destructible_v<Grid<T>>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Width_ReturnWidth) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(5, grid.width());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Height_ReturnHeight) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(3, grid.height());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Size_ReturnWidthTimesHeight) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(15, grid.size());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(MaxSize_GreaterThanOne) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);

        Grid<T>::size_type actual = grid.max_size();

        Assert::IsTrue(actual > 0);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Data_ReturnSameAsBegin) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);
        Assert::IsTrue(*grid.data() == *grid.begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(DataConst_ReturnSameAsBegin) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);
        Grid<T> const& const_grid = std::as_const(grid);
        Assert::IsTrue(*const_grid.data() == *const_grid.begin());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Empty_GridIsEmpty_ReturnTrue) {
        Grid<T> grid;
        Assert::IsTrue(grid.empty());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Empty_GridIsNotEmpty_ReturnFalse) {
        Grid<T> grid(3, 3);
        Assert::IsFalse(grid.empty());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscript_ReturnValue) {
        Grid<T> grid(2, 2);
        *(grid.data() + 2) = 53;

        int& actual = grid[2];

        Assert::AreEqual(53, actual);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscript_WriteToIt_Compiles) {
        Grid<T> grid(2, 2);
        grid[2] = 50;
        Assert::AreEqual(50, grid[2]);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorSubscriptConst_ReturnValue) {
        Grid<T> grid(2, 2);
        *(grid.data() + 2) = 53;
        Grid<T> const& const_grid = std::as_const(grid);

        int const& actual = const_grid[2];

        Assert::AreEqual(53, actual);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(BeginEnd_DifferenceIsSameAsSize) {
        Grid<T> grid(5, 3);
        ptrdiff_t diff = grid.end() - grid.begin();
        Assert::IsTrue(diff == grid.size());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_WhenGridIsNotConst_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Grid<T> grid;

        auto actual = grid.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Grid<T>::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_WhenGridIsNotConst_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Grid<T> grid;

        auto actual = grid.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Grid<T>::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_WhenGridIsConst_ReturnConstIteratorType) {
        Grid<T> const grid;

        auto actual = grid.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Grid<T>::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_WhenGridIsConst_ReturnConstIteratorType) {
        Grid<T> const grid;

        auto actual = grid.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Grid<T>::const_iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Begin_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Grid<T> grid;

        auto actual = grid.begin();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Grid<T>::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(End_ReturnIteratorType) {
        Grid<T> grid;

        auto actual = grid.end();

        Assert::IsTrue(std::is_same_v<decltype(actual), Grid<T>::iterator>);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingRangeFor_EnumerateEachValue) {
        auto grid = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(5, 3);
        int i = 0;

        for(auto&& it : grid)
            Assert::AreEqual(++i, it);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateUsingRangeForConst_EnumerateEachValue) {
        auto const grid = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(5, 3);
        int i = 0;

        for(auto&& it : grid)
            Assert::AreEqual(++i, it);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenSizeMismatch_ReturnFalse) {
        auto a = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(5, 3);
        auto b = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(3, 5);

        Assert::IsFalse(a == b);
        Assert::IsTrue(a != b);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenDataMismatch_ReturnFalse) {
        auto a = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(2, 3);
        auto b = Grid<T>(2, 3);

        Assert::IsFalse(a == b);
        Assert::IsTrue(a != b);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(OperatorComparison_WhenDataMatch_ReturnTrue) {
        auto a = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(2, 3);
        auto b = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(2, 3);

        Assert::IsTrue(a == b);
        Assert::IsFalse(a != b);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Swap_MemberFunction_Swapped) {
        Grid<T> a(2, 3);
        Grid<T> b(3, 2);

        a.swap(b);

        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(3, a.width());
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(2, b.width());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Swap_GlobalFunction_Swapped) {
        Grid<T> a(2, 3);
        Grid<T> b(3, 2);

        swap(a, b);

        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(3, a.width());
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(2, b.width());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Initializer_Width_ReturnWidth) {
        Grid<T> grid{1, 2, {}};
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(1, grid.width());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Initializer_Height_ReturnHeight) {
        Grid<T> grid{1, 2, {}};
        Assert::AreEqual<size_t>(2, grid.height());
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Initializer_Empty_AllItemsHaveDefaultValue) {
        Grid<T> grid{1, 2, {}};
        Assert::IsTrue(std::all_of(grid.begin(), grid.end(), [](int i) { return i == 0; }));
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Initializer_AllItemsInitialized) {
        auto values = {4, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1};

        Grid<T> grid{3, 2, values};

        Assert::IsTrue(std::equal(grid.begin(), grid.end(), values.begin()));
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Initializer_TooManyItems_ExtraItemsIgnored) {
        Grid<T> grid{1, 2, {4, 5, 6, 7}};

        auto expected = {4, 5, 6};
        Assert::IsTrue(std::equal(grid.begin(), grid.end(), expected.begin()));
    }

    TEST_METHOD(Initializer_NotEnoughItems_RemainingItemsHaveDefaultValue) {
        Grid<T> grid{1, 2, {1, 2}};

        auto expected = {1, 2, 0, 0};
        Assert::IsTrue(std::equal(grid.begin(), grid.end(), expected.begin()));
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateRows_EnumerateUsingRangeFor_EnumerateEachRow) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr auto kWidth = 3;
        constexpr auto kHeight = 2;
        auto test_data = assist::CreateIntArray<kWidth * kHeight>();
        Grid<T> grid = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(kWidth, kHeight);
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{kWidth, kHeight};

        //Act
        for(int y{}; Row & row : grid.EnumerateRows()) {
            for(int& cell : row)
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
            ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(test_data);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(EnumerateRows_EnumerateUsingRangeForConst_EnumerateEachRow) {
        //Arrange
        constexpr auto kWidth = 3;
        constexpr auto kHeight = 2;
        auto test_data = assist::CreateIntArray<kWidth * kHeight>();
        Grid<T> const const_grid = assist::CreateFilledGrid<T>(kWidth, kHeight);
        assist::GridVectorAsserter grid_vec{kWidth, kHeight};

        //Act
        for(int y{}; auto&& row : const_grid.EnumerateRows()) {
            for(auto&& cell : row)
                grid_vec.Push(y, cell);
            ++y;
        }

        //Assert
        grid_vec.AssertSameAsArray(test_data);
    }
};
```

##### What's next

After applying any improvements coming from this review, Grid will be done and will be used to implement a color control in a GUI, similar to the HTML5 color picker.

Thank you to everyone spending time on this post.
Althrough it is not needed for the code review, here is a link to the grid.
https://github.com/ShigotoShoujin/shigoto.shoujin/blob/dev/src/grid.hpp

Comment: You have a lot of `[[nodiscard]] constexpr` and `const noexcept` going on. Why?

Comment: `[[nodiscard]]` to warn when there is no point to call the function is the return value is going to be ignored. `constexpr` to make the container work in the context of the `constexpr`. `const` when a member function should not change the class state. And `noexcept` when the function will clearly never throw. Its verbose but so what? :)